# ASP.net Rest API always returns response in JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, odata, bson

I have a ASP.NET REST API, i created ADO.Net entity Data Model with "EF Desinger From Database" from my Maria DB. Entity Framework 6 was used.
I Use Odata v4 Controllers.

My Problem is: I always get Json as Response

I tried:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

and

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "json", "application/json");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "xml", "application/xml");
```

but it made no difference

The Register Method in WebApiConfig.cs looks like this

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();       
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
        builder.EntitySet<mOne>("mOne");
        builder.EntitySet<mTwo>("mTwo");
        builder.EntitySet<mThree>("mThree");

        var defaultConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
        var conventions = new[] {
            new CustomConvetion()
        }.Concat(defaultConventions.Except(
            defaultConventions.OfType<MetadataRoutingConvention>()));
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api",
            builder.GetEdmModel(),
            pathHandler: new CustomPathHandler(),
            routingConventions: conventions);


        //config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("DefaultApi", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());
        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json"));
        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/bson"));
        //var bson = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        //bson.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.contoso"));
        //config.Formatters.Add(bson);
        //config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        //config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        //var xml = config.Formatters(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
        //config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
        //var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
        //xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "json", "application/json");
        //config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "xml", "application/xml");
    }
```

I want to use BSON and JSON as output Formats, but at first i'm ok with it if someone can help me to use anything but Json as output format.

Comment: if you don't provide a recognized mime type in your Accept headers, you will get JSON returned because it is the default format.

Comment: I tried sending requests with Accept Header : application/xml but i still get Json

Comment: Check you Global.asax file and remove it from there, if found there.

Comment: My Global.asax looks like this: 

 `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`

I do not know if i need to remove something from here